# Where can I read about time complexity (Big-O notation) of MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I am interested in complexities (Big O notation) of MySQL queries like "SELECT something WHERE id=1", for example. I am talking about not only one example but some documentaiton where I can read all this stuff how MySQL implements these queries. Is there one? I'll really appreciate if you share this one.

Comment: Complexity theory isn't specific to a particular database.  Start with the theory:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity.  Then you can learn about the algorithms that MySQL uses by looking at the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 9):

I am going to take as your question:  What is the time complexity of the following query in MySQL?

```
SELECT something
FROM t
WHERE id = 1;
```

There are basically two possibilities:  O(log(n)) and O(n).  If the database has an index on `id`, then the look-up is O(log(n)).  Because indexes are stored in memory and table sizes are usually under, say, a trillion rows, this is often approximated as O(1).  The "constant" component of reading the index and setting up the query dominates the time for perusing the index.

The other possibility is O(n).  This means that every row needs to be read to find the one with the right id.  You don't have a `limit` at all, so every row does need to be read, even if the first row matches the condition.

You can imagine that if such a simple query has three potential "right" answers, that more complex queries are even more difficult to analyze.  If you really want to understand performance, you need to learn about complexity theory, the algorithms that databases implement, and the effects of in-memory and out-of-memory data on the algorithms.